# Clion with more than 1 C file

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clion

So i have been using VSCode and back there I had only to make new file save as .C and when I pressed the "run" it automaticly created the "exe" file by themself.

This method is important to me because as I am on programming class, I have the A B C D E F ... exercise to run.

I heard Clion was one of the best tools out there for C, and i have a student acc so decided to try. But here when I create a new project it only lets me run the first file, tried to add a new source file but it fails.

Is there any solution ?
Thanks

[image: this is on VSC]

Comment: You just need to change the executable on the CMakeList.txt

Comment: you mean the  "add_executable()" ? I have to do it for every file ? there is no automatic way just like VSCode ?

Answer (score 1):

CLion uses CMake as makefile generator. I think this question is about CMake "language" and not about CLion. With CMake you can create multiple executables but there is no automatic way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one source file if you want it to run independently in the same project. As you may know there should be only one main function where the program initiates.

Comment: so there is no way to do what i was been doing on VSCode ? i added a image so you can see what i mean

Comment: You can't have more than one main function in the same directory.